# How does Tom Apostol's Calculus Vol 2 defines the term "function"?

Tags: calculus

In section "2.6 Inverses" Tom Apostol's book presents definitions and theorems that worry me. Theorem 2.8 states that a (generic) function $T:U\rightarrow V$ can have only one  left inverse. If T has a left inverse S, then S is also a right inverse.

Linear transformations are functions, and given U and V are finite dimensional spaces with fixed bases, there is exactly one matrix that represents given transformation and each matrix induces transformation.

More precisely, if we represent the matrices as functions that map the indices (i,j) to a value, there is isomorphism between the vector space of all $m\times n$ matrices and the vector space of all linear transformations between U and W, given U and V have dimensions m and n.

Transferring the above facts to the matrices led me to the conclusion, that a non-square matrix can have at most one left inverse. If we pick say $3\times 4$ matrix B, then there is at most one $4\times 3$ matrix A such that $AB=I_{4}$. This is because each of the matrices induces linear transformation and since the transformation, corresponding to A is unique, the matrix must be unique too.

This though, is wrong. Some computations in WA showed that in the general case there are many possible matrices A, such that AB=I and many (all?) of them are not right inverses.

This led me to reexamine my old and rusty set theory knowledge of injective and surjective functions and I discovered to my horror, that Apostol seems to define function as mapping the domain into the range. That is, all functions are onto their codomains. Only this way he can conclude that each function has at least one right inverse and at most one left inverse.

But going this way implies that we cannot call a linear transformation something that maps $R^2$ into $R^5$ (for example multiplication of two dimensional vector by $5\times 2$ matrix), because this clearly is not surjection.

I'm worried of two things. The first one is that something in the my argument so far is flawed, and the second one is that the argument is actually correct and the proofs of the book are somewhat flawed.

I got him on page 32 for example, where he stated that "The zero transformation maps every element of V onto O" as example for linear transformation. This one is definitely not surjection.

Any help, ideas, encouraging thoughts?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It is false that if $T:U\to V$ is a function it can have at most one left inverse. Let $U=\{0,1\}$ and $V=\{0,1,2\}$. Let $T$ be the inclusion. There are two functions $A,B:V\to U$ which are different but are both left inverses. $A(0)=0=B(0),A(1)=1=B(1)$ is forced but we could define $A(2)=0$ and $B(2)=1$ with no trouble.

Comment: This is exactly the crux of the argument. It seems that Apostol views functions as always surjective. That is their codomain is always equal to their range. 
If I correctly interpret "T is an inclusion" in your example, this means that T(0)=0 and T(1)=1. Then, according to Apostol, the codomain of T is {0,1}, not {0,1,2}.

Comment: If Apostol really views all functions as surjective then that is a laughable position. The only thing this achieves is notational difficulty

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are missing is that Apostol sees all functions as being onto their **ranges**, rather than codomains. In that sense, a linear transformation taking from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^5$ is indeed onto its range in $\mathbb{R}^5$, which is a subspace of dimension 2 or less (let's call this subspace $R$). Now there can be infinetely many transformations taking $\mathbb{R}^5$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that their composition with our first one will result in the indentity in $\mathbb{R}^2$, however they should all agree in all points of $R$, and therefore when restricted to $R$, they are all the same.

In the same way, the null transformation is a surjection onto $\{0\}$, where $0$ is the null vector of whichever vector space that is the codomain.

Comment: Exactly my conclusion. But I think he may be using the results for the functions, understood as always surjective, to the more generic theorems, regarding mapping between vector spaces where linear transformations are not surjective. 
If he does that, I'll catch him ;-). Just 500 or so more pages to go...

Comment: Understanding functions as always onto their range, that in this case is their codomain, is somewhat "retro", right?

Comment: To be sincere, I'm not sure, it's been quite a while since I last studied functions' definitions. But I think as long as his assumptions are consistent, everything should hold, and for what I know, Apostol is a great book for multivariable calculus, so I guess you are good to go  ;)